# how to use two buttons for showing the same Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

What should I do, if I want that two different buttons launch an Intent to the same Activity? for example: I have 1. button "Flowers", and 2. button "Sky", and the user pushes either the "sky" or the "flowers" button, s/he gets the same Activity, ListOfChildren.

Comment: Just put the same listener body for both buttons?

Comment: can you explain what you want in same activity ListOfChidren means?

Comment: I need 2 different button and different Listener..

Comment: If you need two different buttons, create them two in your XML and wire them in within your activity. 
Two different listener, just create btn1.setOnClickListener and same for button 2.

Comment: @Vij "ListOfChildren" this is the Activity and this ia what I need that user get from two diffrent button the same Activity..

Comment: @Nero I do this now I need to pass to Activity..

Comment: Intent intentListofChidren = new Intent(ListOfChildren.this,ListOfChildren.class) ; startActivity(intentListofChidren); finish();

Comment: @Nero Thank you very much now it work  like I want :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
startActivity(this, ListOfChildren.class);
```

In your onClick methods of both buttons
or point two buttons to same onClick method

Comment: correct, and it would be event better to just create one listener and set it to both buttons

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into both of your `<button>` widgets in `.xml` file:

`android:onClick="gotoListOfChildren"`

Now add a method in your activity as:

`public void gotoListOfChildren(View v) {`
   `Intent i;`
   `i = new Intent(this, ListOfChildren.class);`
`startActivity(i);`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

Set onclick listners for 2 buttons inside the oncreate method. Then set same activity to be start using intent.

```
final Button btnFlowers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id); //get flower button id from xml layout
final Button btnSky = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id); ////get sky button id from xml layout

btnFlowers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {  
                          Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);        
                          // currentContext.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);        
                          PresentActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
                        }
                      });
btnSky.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {            
                          Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);        
                          // currentContext.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);        
                          PresentActivity.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
                        }
                      });
```